# Get bored of/with/by/from doing something (Which one is correct?)

Tags: prepositions, participial-adjectives

I have seen people use the forms/expressions "*to get bored of*", "*to get bored with*", "*to get bored by*", "*to get bored from*." I would like to know which is the correct one to use when it is followed by a gerund as a non. Which one do you recommend?

If all of them are correct, when should I use each one?

Examples:

> 1. John was getting bored **of** doing the same thing every day.
> 2. John was getting bored **with** doing the same thing every day.
> 3. John was getting bored **by** doing the same thing every day.
> 4. John was getting bored **from** doing the same thing every day.

Comment: They are all grammatical. There's no way of stating which should be used. You could also leave out the word altogether: *John was getting bored doing the same thing every day.*

Comment: If I can drop the preposition, what is the reason for it to be there when it should? Does the presence of the preposition not express "_the reason_"? Also, I wonder why I can drop it in those examples and not when I say "_I am tired **of** eating beans every day_."

Comment: Each preposition gives a slightly different nuance to the sentence. English has thousands of ways of saying the same thing in different words. Also *I am getting tired eating beans every day* is fine, but it means something else. Also, *getting tired* and *getting tired* ***of*** are different. It's *getting* that makes the difference in that example. But, additionally, *getting tired of eating* and *getting tired eating* do mean something quite different. In many cases, the specific context can make a huge difference. It's very difficult (if not impossible) to have general rules here.

Comment: I'd say they're all okay, but to rank from most natural-sounding to least: 1,2,4,3

Comment: I wonder if "_I am getting tired eating beans_" means "_I am eating beans now and I am becoming exhausted._"

Comment: @JasonBassford would you consider expanding your comment into an answer? Even if there is no general rule, IMO it's still worth pointing out the nuances of meaning using the OP's example sentences as context.

Comment: @RuslanD There's no way I can provide a proper answer for this. I've also already voted to close the question as opinion based. Any subtle differences I see in the example sentences in the question could be seen differently by somebody else. There are too many dictionary definitions of the prepositions (and the overall grammar), as well as, I suspect, a lack of their use with *bored* specifically, to point to anything objective. At least not without writing a book about it.

Comment: @JasonBassford I understand. As a non-native speaker myself, English prepositions were, perhaps, the hardest thing to get right, and I still don't think I'm there 100% of the time. I found that things clicked when I discussed specific examples with people, rather than when I read the detail-laden dictionary definitions of the prepositions. I believe there is value in at least explaining to the OP what the subtle differences are between their concrete example sentences, so even if I can't sway you to provide an answer, at least please reconsider getting the question closed.

Comment: @RuslanD The best I can say is what I've already said. Especially for anybody starting out with English, it really doesn't matter which preposition is used here. Each will be as essentially understood as any other. Even for people who've spoken English for years and come to understand the extremely subtle difference, it doesn't make *enough* of a difference to call out as any kind of style rule. It's like telling a person which food item they *should* be ordering from a menu when everybody has different tastes. So, when I say it doesn't matter which preposition is used here it really doesn't …

Comment: In fact, it's much more subtle than picking a food item. This *particular* question is like asking if you should get your car painted red or painted blue. (Which colour is correct?) Each person will have a different opinion, and it will make no practical difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Macmillan Dictionary blog has a nice [article](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/real-grammar-quiz-question-3-bored-with-it-or-bored-of-it) about "bored with" vs. "bored of". The conclusion is that they are interchangeable, with the latter being considered a newer usage in the language (also corroborated by other comparisons between the two you can find online, such as [this one](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/01/bored.html)). The Cambridge Dictionary's entry for [bored](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bored) shows examples with both "with" and "of", as well as an example of where it's OK to drop the preposition altogether.

"bored by" seems to be another equivalent way of saying the same thing. It [seems](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Word_by_Word/3komDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bored+by%22&pg=PA76&printsec=frontcover) like it was a popular choice in the past on par with "bored with". It's still not unpopular today - take a look at all these [examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bored+by%22) from printed books. Personally, I'd use it when I want to emphasize the feeling of boredom, rather than that something is boring, but I can't claim that's a general rule:

> I'm bored **by** this presentation. (= This presentation makes me *feel bored*).
>
> I'm bored **of**/**with** this presentation. (= This presentation *seems boring* to me.)

"bored from" means "bored as a result of", as you can see in the comments section of this Bored Panda (ahem) [article](https://www.boredpanda.com/funny-bored-people-quarantine-activities/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organic). So you wouldn't typically say "I'm bored *from* you" (= bored as a result of you ??). I suggest looking it up in Google Books as well to get additional examples of how it's used.